# NoClassDefError com.liferay.mobile.screens.base.interactor.JSONObjectCallback in Liferay Screens Android

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, liferay

I am using Liferay Screens in my Android Mobile app, together with Liferay Android Mobile SDK. 
I have put a LoginScreenlet into my activity. It shows correctly, but when I click the Login button, I get this error:

```
05-08 10:58:37.681 9296-9296/com.mimacom.lrhc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                            java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.liferay.mobile.screens.base.interactor.JSONObjectCallback
                                                                at com.liferay.mobile.screens.auth.login.interactor.LoginBasicInteractor.getUserService(LoginBasicInteractor.java:68)
                                                                at com.liferay.mobile.screens.auth.login.interactor.LoginBasicInteractor.login(LoginBasicInteractor.java:37)
                                                                at com.liferay.mobile.screens.auth.login.LoginScreenlet.onUserAction(LoginScreenlet.java:236)
                                                                at com.liferay.mobile.screens.auth.login.LoginScreenlet.onUserAction(LoginScreenlet.java:44)
                                                                at com.liferay.mobile.screens.base.BaseScreenlet.performUserAction(BaseScreenlet.java:78)
                                                                at com.liferay.mobile.screens.viewsets.defaultviews.auth.login.LoginView.onClick(LoginView.java:136)
                                                                at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                                                                at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I am trying this on Genymotion emulator, Android 4.1.1 (Level 16).

My app's gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.neenbedankt.android-apt'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.hugo'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mimacom.lrhc"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility "1.7"
        targetCompatibility "1.7"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
        mock {}
        prod {}
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //Support libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:23.3.0'
    //RxJava
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0'
    compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.3'
    //Butterknife view injection
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.1'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.1'
    //Dagger dependency injection
    apt 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.2'
    compile 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.2'
    provided 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    //Memory leak detector
    debugCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:1.4-beta2'
    releaseCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    testCompile 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android-no-op:1.4-beta2'
    //Liferay SDK and Screens
    compile group: 'com.liferay.mobile', name: 'liferay-android-sdk', version: '6.2.0.22'
    compile 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-screens:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.liferay.mobile:liferay-material-viewset:1.3.0'
}
```

I have found a forum post about a similar problem, but that's for older version of Liferay Screens. I guess 1.3.0 should already be compatible. https://web.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/60438799

Is it indeed a dependency problem or is it something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a dependency problem, the 6.2.0.22 is an older version and screens 1.3.0 is using a newer one with breaking API changes.

You don't need the dependency against the mobile SDK, you can use the one embedded in screens (after updating some code documented on the doc in https://github.com/liferay/liferay-screens/blob/develop/android/Migrate%20to%20Liferay%20Screens%201.2.md

Comment: Thanks. However, i would then suggest to update this page: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-mobile-sdk/blob/master/android/README.md because i used that version in my gradle build file and got the 6.x version which caused me trouble.